# htaccess mod_rewrite exclude images/css

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I have created a simple mod rewrite for my site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(cgi-bin|css|images|js|gfx)/?.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^filter/model/([^/]*)/mins/([^/]*)/texts/([^/]*)/freegifts/([^/]*)/network/([^/]*)/merchant/([^/]*)$ /fiverrr.php?model=$1&mins=$2&texts=$3&freegifts=$4&network=$5&merchant=$6 [L]
```

but it doesn't seem to be working (as in all the images/js etc don't show up)

e.g. `http://mydomain.com/filter/model/Sony+Ericsson+Xperia+Arc+S+White/mins/+3000/texts/+-1/freegifts/FREE+Nintendo+3DS+Black/network/Orange/merchant/`

original url: `http://mydomain.com/fiverrr.php?model=Sony+Ericsson+Xperia+Arc+S+White&mins=+3000&texts=+-1&freegifts=FREE+Nintendo+3DS+Black&network=Orange&merchant=Contract`

Where am I going wrong, and is this the best method?

Thanks so much

Comment: Shouldn't the RewriteCond come before the RewriteRule?

Comment: Yes it should.  Swap them around and the rule won't fire for /css/... URIs, etc.

Comment: I swapped them around and the URL never worked :(

Comment: Check your access logs to see what image URIs are being requested. Are you using absolute URIs for your images etc or relative ones?  Remember that if you are using relative URIs, then SEO-style URI will confuse the browser unless you specify a base meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put there another condition - htaccess will rewrite it only if requested file does not exist:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^filter/model/([^/]*)/mins/([^/]*)/texts/([^/]*)/freegifts/([^/]*)/network/([^/]*)/merchant/([^/]*)$ /fiverrr.php?model=$1&mins=$2&texts=$3&freegifts=$4&network=$5&merchant=$6 [L]
```

Also I recomend you to check full paths. Check if you have images in HTML code like: `http://mydomain.com/images/img.jpg` - relative paths like `./../images/img.jpg` will not work!